# Игнорировать всё, кроме файлов в подпапке

Tags: git, gitignore

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать файл gitignnore таким образом, чтобы видеть файлы в подпапке, но не в папке. Так схематично выглядит структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]

Мне нужно, чтобы в репозитории были файлы 3 и 4, которые лежат в folder1/folder2/, а остальные (папка folder3 и obd, файлы 1 и 2) игнорировались.

Я пробовал следующее решение:

```
1: /*
2: !/folder1
3: /folder1/
4: !/folder1/folder2/
```

Логика у меня была такая:

1: игнорируй всё

2: кроме папки folder1 (работает и показывает все содержимое folder1)

3: игнорируй все содержимое папки folder1 (работает)

4: кроме папки folder2 (вот тут перестает работать)

Структура проекта очень упрощена, по факту folder1 содержит несколько десятков папок с **тысячами** файлов - поэтому добавлять вручную в игнор - плохое решение.

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почти правильно, только звёздочку в пункте 3 забыли. И у вас получилось не «игнорируй содержимое папки folder1», а «игнорируй папку folder1».

Вот так будет работать:

```
/*
!/folder1
/folder1/*
!/folder1/folder2/
```

Comment: Спасибо, так действительно работает. Обнаружил дополнительную ошибку - folder2 уже была в репозитории и манипуляции с ней через gitignore не приносили результата. Удалил и заново добавил - все работает правильно!